# node_modules structure remains flat even after removing and re-installing

Tags: node.js, npm

Originally I think that my `node_modules` folder had one subfolder for each of the packages specified in my `package.json` file.

Then, some time ago, I think I ran:

```
$ npm dedupe
```

to flatten the structure and avoid duplicated packages in `node_modules`.

But now, the `node_modules` folder seems to have retained the de-duped structure, even after I go through the following upgrade / uninstall / reinstall process:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ ncu -a
$ npm install
```

After this, `node_modules` is again filled with hundreds of sub-folders, in a flat, de-duped structure.

Not that it matters much (de-duped is fine), but I'm curious to know why it hasn't gone back to the hierarchical structure... maybe there's a setting somewhere I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your NPM version was upgraded to v3+ at some point after your `node_modules` was initially setup. Not much you can do now unless you downgrade to NPM v2 or earlier.

NPM v3+ uses a flat dependency structure to reduce package duplication and nesting.

- Read more about NPM v3 dependency resolution [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).
- Read more about NPM v2 dependency resolution [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm2)

Comment: ah ok so it was nothing to do with my previous de-dupe... just a change in default behaviour... the new default behaviour seems sensible so I'll stick with that.